# How to manage desktops and polybar on BSPWM with MULTIPLE MONITORS

Tags: bash, shell-script

I use bspwm as my window manager. I've been using it on my desktop for long and now I've also using it on my laptop, but here it's a bit more difficult to operate.

I use a tool called [mons](https://github.com/Ventto/mons) to auto-handle my "screen layouts". I run it as a daemon on my bspwmrc, and when I unplug an external monitor, it auto-changes to only laptop screen. Nice.

The problem is, my laptop has two graphics cards: AMD integrated and Nvidia dedicated. Here is the thing, to `xrandr` I have:

- When running with the integrated AMD:

  - laptop display: `eDP-1`
  - external DisplayPort 1: `DP-1`
  - external DisplayPort 2: `DP-2`
  - external HDMI: `HDMI-1`
- When dedicated NVIDIA:

  - laptop display: `eDP-1-1`
  - external DP: `DP-1-1`
  - external DP: `DP-1-2`
  - `HDMI-1-1`

To make it simpler, I need to distinguish from:

- AMD only
- Nvidia only
- AMD + Display port (only the number 1 (so, `eDP-1`))
- Nvidia + Display port 1 (`eDP-1-1`)

I would want to tell my bspwm to grep on the results of `xrandr` and act accordingly distributing my workspaces. If done manually, I run:

- If there is only the laptop screen (it doesn't need to tell if its running on the AMD or the nvidia one):

  ```
  bspc monitor -d I II III IV V VI VII VIII IX X
  ```
- If it is running with AMD integrated + external DisplayPort:

  ```
  bspc monitor eDP-1 -d I II III IV V
  bspc monitor DP-1 -d VI VII VIII IX X
  ```
- If it is running with nvidia dedicated + external monitor on Displayport:

  ```
  bspc monitor eDP-1-1 -d I II III IV V
  bspc monitor DP-1-1 -d VI VII VIII IX X
  ```

How can I write an if / else decision to check whether there is `eDP-1`, `DP-1`, `eDP-1-1` or `DP-1-1` and act accordingly?

I really don't know any bash, scripting or programming, so I really don't know how to make it properly. Can you guys help me??

I hope I explained myself well enough!

P.S.: The `^` in front of DP is to grep a line that **starts** with that capital P, otherwise it would also find the laptop screen.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after hours of try and error, I finally did it. I also learned how to use if statements on scripts, so it was worth it.

It was resolved as follows:

```
amddp=$(xrandr --query | grep '^DP-1')
nvidiadp=$(xrandr --query | grep '^DP-1-1 connected')
if [[ $amddp = *\ connected* ]]; then
        bspc monitor eDP-1 -d I II III IV V
        bspc monitor DP-1 -d VI VII VIII IX X
elif [[ $nvidiadp = *\ connected* ]]; then
        bspc monitor eDP-1-1 -d I II III IV V
        bspc monitor DP-1-1 -d VI VII VIII IX X
else
        bspc monitor -d I II III IV V VI VII VIII IX X
fi
```

To understand it a bit:

- when it greps for `^`DP-1 (it means *a line that starts with* DP-1, to avoid the laptop's eDP-1 screen.
- When it says `= *\ connected*`, it means equal to:

  - `*` any character or group of characters (I used it so I didn't have to write on the script the entire line that the grep command would output).
  - `\`  (backslash space) actually means the space character. Otherwise, when I disconnect the monitor, it still appears when grepping for `*connected*` as "disconnected" includes the word "connected" on it .

I also used the same structure to launch diferent polybar.sh scripts to launch either one bar on laptop monitor (one .sh for the nvidia, and one for the amd), or two bars, one on laptop and one on external monitor. Each .sh points to one or two configs.ini of the corresponding polybars.

Hope it helps somebody!